# av_read_frame function in ffmpeg in android always returning packet.stream_index as 0

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, libavformat

I am using the following standard code pasted below (ref: http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/) to use ffmpeg in android using ndk. My code is working fine in ubuntu 10.04 using gcc compiler. But I am facing an issue in android.The issue is `av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet)` is always returning `packet.stream_index=0`. I have tested my code with various rtsp urls and I have the same behaviour in all cases. I do not have any linking or compiling issues as everything seems to be working fine except this issue. I am trying to solve this from last 2 days but I am stuck badly.Please point me in right direction.

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>

#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#define DEBUG_TAG "mydebug_ndk"

jint Java_com_example_tut2_MainActivity_myfunc(JNIEnv * env, jobject this,jstring myjurl) {
  AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
  int             i, videoStream;
  AVCodecContext  *pCodecCtx = NULL;
  AVCodec         *pCodec = NULL;
  AVFrame         *pFrame = NULL;
  AVPacket        packet;
  int             frameFinished;

  AVDictionary    *optionsDict = NULL;
  struct SwsContext *sws_ctx = NULL;

  jboolean isCopy;
  const char * mycurl = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, myjurl, &isCopy);
  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "NDK:p2: [%s]", mycurl);

  // Register all formats and codecs
  av_register_all();
  avformat_network_init();
  // Open video file
  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "NDK:before_open");

  if(avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, mycurl, NULL, NULL)!=0)
      return -1;
  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "start: %d\t%d\n",pFormatCtx->raw_packet_buffer_remaining_size,pFormatCtx->max_index_size);

  (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, myjurl, mycurl);
  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "NDK:before_stream");
  // Retrieve stream information
  if(avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL)<0)
      return -1;
  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "NDK:after_stream");
  // Find the first video stream
  videoStream=-1;
  for(i=0; i<pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
      if(pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        videoStream=i;
        break;
      }
  if(videoStream==-1)
      return -1; // Didn't find a video stream
  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "NDK:after_videostream");
  // Get a pointer to the codec context for the video stream
  pCodecCtx=pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->codec;
  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "NDK:after_codec_context");

  // Find the decoder for the video stream
  pCodec=avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtx->codec_id);
  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "NDK:after_decoder");

  if(pCodec==NULL)
      return -1;
  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "NDK:found_decoder");

  // Open codec
  if(avcodec_open2(pCodecCtx, pCodec, &optionsDict)<0)
      return -1;
  // Allocate video frame
  pFrame=avcodec_alloc_frame();
  sws_ctx = sws_getContext(pCodecCtx->width,pCodecCtx->height,pCodecCtx->pix_fmt,pCodecCtx->width,
        pCodecCtx->height,PIX_FMT_YUV420P,SWS_BILINEAR,NULL,NULL,NULL);
  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "NDK:before_while");

  int count=0;
  while(av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet)>=0) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "entered while: %d   %d   %d\n", packet.duration,packet.stream_index,packet.size);

      if(packet.stream_index==videoStream) {
          // Decode video frame
          //break;
          avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished,&packet);
          __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "NDK:in_while");
          if(frameFinished) {
              __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "NDK:gng_out_of_while");
                break;
          }
      }

      // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
      av_free_packet(&packet);
      if(++count>1000)
         return -2; //infinite while loop
  }
  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "NDK:after_while");

  // Free the YUV frame
  av_free(pFrame);
  // Close the codec
  avcodec_close(pCodecCtx);
  // Close the video file
  avformat_close_input(&pFormatCtx);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: I have same problam too. Hopes someone can help us. :(

Answer (score 0):

I have same problam too.
after my test, I'v found my mistake, Hopes can help you.

my av_read_frame() also always return av_pkg of stream index 0;

***The problem is: I mixed two version of ffmpeg libs.***

At before, I'v install the ffmpeg of 0.9.x
Now, I install ffmpeg of 1.2

the libs are in different version.I used some lib from 0.9.x  and others from 1.2.
So... error occur.

I solution:

uninstall all version of ffmpeg , and then reinstall one version of ffmpeg(me->1.2).
The av_read_frame() goes right. :)

Comment: I experienced a similar problem and solution to dinosaur. My project was using ffmpeg v2.0 libraries but including headers from v1.2.1. The versions are just similar enough to avoid compile errors but different enough to cause data alignment problems with AVPacket.